# Three non isomorphic abelian groups of order 27...

Tags: abstract-algebra

...And explain why all other abelian groups are isomorphic to each other.

I have attached my solution so far. I have found three abelian groups of order 27 but I am not sure if they are isomorphic. And are all other abelian groups isomorphic to one of them? Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

By the structure theorem for finite abelian group, every finite abelian group is isomorphic to a direct sum of cyclic groups. Since the order of a product of finite groups is the product of the orders, the three groups that you listed are the only possibilities (up to isomorphism of course). In fact they are also pairwise non-isomorphic, since in the first one every nonzero element has order $3$, in the second there is an element of order $9$ but no elements of order $27$ and in the third one there is an element of order $27$.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean direct product though?

Comment: direct sum and direct product of a finite number of groups are the same object... so say direct product if you prefer!